# multiple selection issue in custom linearlayout android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-framelayout

I have a list of  templates each template in  framelayout, 
each  template  has  main image and  6  retangles representing colors (see the image)

[image]

When I click on rectangle in the list it gets the focus and border color changes . and it stays  selected even if i click on other  template
I want only one to be selected at a time, here is the code for the template class.

```
package com.v12software.android.website.selecttemplate;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.koushikdutta.async.future.FutureCallback;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.DisplayImageOptions;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoaderConfiguration;
import com.v12software.android.R;
import com.v12software.android.Activities.V12BaseActivity;
import com.v12software.android.Managers.ServiceManager;
import com.v12software.android.Managers.WebTemplate;
import com.v12software.android.custom.NavWidget;
import com.v12software.android.custom.NavWidget.OnClickListener;
import com.v12software.android.custom.TemplateView;
import com.v12software.android.reqs.IonAPIReqs;
import com.v12software.android.utils.SharedPrefUtils;

public class SelecttemplateActivity extends V12BaseActivity {

    private NavWidget nav_bar_home;
    public static LinearLayout listemplates;
    public static String selectedSkinId = "0";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_select_templates);

        ImageLoader.getInstance().init(
                new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(this)
                        .defaultDisplayImageOptions(
                                new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                                        .cacheInMemory(true).cacheOnDisk(true)
                                        .build()).build());

        nav_bar_home = (NavWidget) findViewById(R.id.nav_bar);
        listemplates = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.templateContainer);
        nav_bar_home.addOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onNavBtnClicked(View view) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.left_tv:
                    SelecttemplateActivity.this.onBackPressed();
                    finish();
                    break;
                case R.id.center_tv:

                    break;
                case R.id.right_tv:
                    // save template to server
                    save();
                    break;
                }
            }
        });

        try {
            new Loadtemplates().execute().get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        nav_bar_home.setButtonTitles(R.string.nav_back,
                R.string.website_select_template,
                R.string.vehicledetails_dlg_unsavedchanges_save);
    }

    private class Loadtemplates extends AsyncTask<String, String, ArrayList<WebTemplate>> {

        ArrayList<WebTemplate> templates = new ArrayList<WebTemplate>();

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        }

        protected ArrayList<WebTemplate> doInBackground(String... args) {
            try {
                templates = ServiceManager.Current
                        .get_all_templates(SharedPrefUtils
                                .getAuthToken(getApplicationContext()));

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return templates;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<WebTemplate> webTemplates) {
            for (WebTemplate wt : webTemplates) {
                TemplateView tv = new TemplateView(getApplicationContext(), wt);
                tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                listemplates.addView(tv);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

    }

//  @Override
//  public void onNavBtnClicked(View view) {
//      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//      switch (view.getId()) {
//      case R.id.left_tv:
//          SelecttemplateActivity.this.onBackPressed();
//          finish();
//          break;
//      case R.id.center_tv:
//
//          break;
//      case R.id.right_tv:
//          // save template to server
//          save();
//          break;
//      }
//  }

    private void save() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        IonAPIReqs.savetemplate(getApplicationContext(), SharedPrefUtils.getAuthToken(getApplicationContext()),selectedSkinId , new FutureCallback<JsonObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onCompleted(Exception arg0, JsonObject arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(IonAPIReqs.isReqSuccess(arg1))
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Saving Template", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

and here is the  code  for the main class  instantiating the  first one

```
package com.v12software.android.custom;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader;
import com.v12software.android.R;
import com.v12software.android.Managers.WebTemplate;
import com.v12software.android.website.selecttemplate.SelecttemplateActivity;

public class TemplateView extends LinearLayout {

    private Context cntx;

    private WebTemplate webTemplate;
    private ArrayList<BorderView> colorsIVs;
    /** The inflater. */
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    private LinearLayout colorsLayout;

    private ImageView templateIV;

    public WebTemplate getWebTemplate() {
        return webTemplate;
    }

    public void setWebTemplate(WebTemplate webTemplate) {
        this.webTemplate = webTemplate;
    }

    public TemplateView(Context context, WebTemplate webtemplate) {
        super(context);
        this.webTemplate = webtemplate;
        this.colorsIVs = new ArrayList<BorderView>();
        setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        this.cntx = getContext();
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(cntx);
        this.inflater.inflate(R.layout.template_litem, this);
        this.colorsLayout = ((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.liearlayoutimages));
        this.templateIV = ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mainimage));

        for (int i = 0; i < webTemplate.getColors().size(); i++) {
            String selectedColor = webTemplate.getColors().get(i);
            final String selectedSkin = webTemplate.getIds().get(i);
            ImageView colorIV = new ImageView(cntx);
            colorIV.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(selectedColor));

            BorderView borderV = new BorderView(cntx, colorIV);
            LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(100, 100);
            lparams.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);
            borderV.setLayoutParams(lparams);
            borderV.setTag(selectedColor);
            colorsIVs.add(borderV);

            ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(
                    webTemplate.getfisrturltoshow(), templateIV);
            borderV.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(selectedSkin,
                            templateIV);
                    SelecttemplateActivity.selectedSkinId = selectedSkin
                            .replace(
                                    "http://cdn-w.v12soft.com/photos/templates/images/template-",
                                    "").replace(".jpg", "");

                    for (BorderView btn : colorsIVs) {
                        if (btn != (BorderView) v) {
                        //  colorsLayout.invalidate();
                        //  colorsLayout.refreshDrawableState();

//                          SelecttemplateActivity.listemplates.invalidate();
//                          SelecttemplateActivity.listemplates.refreshDrawableState();
                            btn.removeSelectionBorder();
//                          for(int i=0;i<SelecttemplateActivity.listemplates.getChildCount();i++){
//                              TemplateView tt = (TemplateView)    SelecttemplateActivity.listemplates.getChildAt(i);
//                              for(int k=0;k<tt.getChildCount();k++){
//                                  
//                                  BorderView ti   = (BorderView) tt.getChildAt(k);
//                                  ti.removeSelectionBorder();
//                              }
//                              
                             //Log.v("linear children count ", ""+ln.rem);

                    //  }
                        }else{
                            ((BorderView) v).addSelectionBorder();
                            Log.v("linear children count ", ""+SelecttemplateActivity.listemplates.getChildCount());
                        }
                    }
                    //Toast.makeText(getContext(), "gt children count"+colorsLayout.getChildCount(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    //Toast.makeText(getContext(), "gt children count"+SelecttemplateActivity.listemplates.getChildCount(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//                  for(int i=0;i<SelecttemplateActivity.listemplates.getChildCount();i++){
//                      TemplateView ln=(TemplateView)  SelecttemplateActivity.listemplates.getChildAt(i);
//                       Log.v("linear children count ", ""+ln.getChildCount());
//                  }

                    //colorsLayout.getParent().recomputeViewAttributes(v);

                }
            });
            colorsLayout.addView(borderV);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
    }

    static class BorderView extends FrameLayout {
        public ImageView imageView;

        public BorderView(Context context, ImageView iv) {
            super(context);
            this.imageView = iv;
            setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            addView(imageView);
        }

        public ImageView getImageView() {
            return imageView;
        }

        public void setImageView(ImageView imageView) {
            this.imageView = imageView;
        }

        public void addSelectionBorder() {
            int border = 8;
            setPadding(border, border, border, border);
            setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#26FF00"));
        }

        public void removeSelectionBorder() {
            int border = 0;
            setPadding(border, border, border, border);
            setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should deselect all other border views from other templates that you have in your code. To do so :

1- add this method in the TemplateView class :

```
private void deselectOtherBorderViews(TemplateView currentSelectedTemplate, LinearLayout layoutTemplateContainer) {
    if (layoutTemplateContainer != null) {
        int childCount = layoutTemplateContainer.getChildCount();
        if (childCount > 0) {
            int currentSelectedTemplateTag = (Integer) currentSelectedTemplate.getTag();
            for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
                View currentChild = layoutTemplateContainer.getChildAt(i);
                if (currentChild != null) {
                    // cast the current view to a web template
                    TemplateView currentTemplate = (TemplateView) currentChild;
                    int currentTemplateTag = (Integer) currentTemplate.getTag();

                    if (currentTemplateTag != currentSelectedTemplateTag) {
                        // deselect the border view of the currentTemplate
                        ArrayList<BorderView> currentTemplateColorsIVs = currentTemplate.getColorsIVs();
                        if (currentTemplateColorsIVs != null && !currentTemplateColorsIVs.isEmpty()) {
                            for (BorderView btn : currentTemplateColorsIVs) {
                                btn.removeSelectionBorder();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

2- Call it in the onClick() method ( when a user click on a color in a specific template view :

```
borderV.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Deselect other border views from other web template views
                deselectOtherBorderViews(TemplateView.this, SelecttemplateActivity.listemplates);
// The rest of your code...
```

NB : Don't forget to set integer tags to your template views while loading them in the onPostExecute() :

```
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<WebTemplate> webTemplates) {
        int counter = 0;
        for (WebTemplate wt : webTemplates) {
            TemplateView tv = new TemplateView(getApplicationContext(), wt);
            tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            tv.setTag(counter);
            counter++;
            listemplates.addView(tv);
        }
```

Hope it helps.